# How to avoid DRY by keep re-assigning variable

Tags: javascript

I have a module where when each function is executed, it reassigns the value of the variable. This variable is stored in the constructor as I want to use it across modules. How can I do this without repeating myself?

```
function FormatText(data) {
  this._data = data;
}

FormatText.prototype.toDowncase = function() {
  return this._data = this._data.toLowerCase();
};

FormatText.prototype.deleteWords = function() {
  return this._data = this._data.replace(/\W/g, " ");
};

FormatText.prototype.splitWords = function() {
  return this._data = this._data.split(/\s+/);
};

FormatText.prototype.filterEntries = function() {
  return this._data = this._data.filter(v => !!v);
};

FormatText.prototype.countWords = function() {
  return this._data = this._data.reduce((dict, v) => {dict[v] = v in dict ? dict[v] + 1 : 1; return dict}, {});
}

module.exports = FormatText;
```

Comment: Is it really worth doing? What you have here is quite clear. Minimizing the code may increase confusion.

Comment: I appreciate the reply. I am only trying to avoid the rule of 'not repeating yourself' as apparently this is a 'strict rule' to adhere in.

Comment: Unless this seems like worthy code?

Comment: Using ES6 class removes the need to write `FormatText.prototype.` and `= function()` for each method.

Comment: @monkeybanana - like the pirate code - it's more of a guideline :)

Comment: @OriDrori Fair enough. Thanks :)

Comment: If you "avoid DRY" then you **are** repeating yourself. ;-)

Comment: You could define these filters as something that operate directly on `this` and then use binding with `apply` to shift the meaning of `this` but that probably over-complicates things here. The real question I have is why this code exists in this form. Having these as a collection of helper methods that take one argument is *considerably* less code.

Comment: Sorry I’m struggling to see what you mean by having a helper method. Can you give me an example with relevance to my code above?